# Kernel Keeps Dying when Running the Jupyter Notebook import cell

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to run a Python Jupyter Notebook for a Deep Learning Algorithm.
The problem I keep running into is that the kernel keeps dying whenever I try to run even the import statements. I am slightly confused as to what is going on due to the fact that I have ran other similar notebooks without any issues. If it helps it is a GAN MINST computation. I am running Jupyter Notebooks from from an Anaconda installation and I did upgrade to the latest version with conda. Here is the import statement which is where it fails without even getting to the code.

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import os, time, itertools, imageio, pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

I appreciate any help or feedback!

Comment: @Mariusmarten Thank you for your response and for the tip regarding posting code. I do believe I might have an older version of tensorflow so I will try to update it now.

Comment: If you have a M1 Mac, you might have installed the wrong tensorflow, by this I mean the wrong architecture (x86_64) which will not work even using Rosetta due to the use of AVX instructions. In that case you need to install an ARM version of tensorflow (like the one Apple makes).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks, I ended up using Google Colaboratory. I have to use it in class often so I had used it before in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be cause by the use of an old Tensorflow version. This is the associated issue:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31870

A solution might be to update your Tensorflow version. Please also make sure to write your code as an actual code cell when posting such questions (using `  3 times gives you `code` ).

Comment: I tried updating tensor flow but it was already at the latest version. I had used pip to install. I am on macOS if that adds any clarification.

Comment: I also update but still have the same problem